# Entity Framework Save changes on Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have this piece of code

```
public int Update(Item item)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataConext())
    {
        ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}

Class Item
{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public ICollection<Foobar> Foos {get;set;}
}

Class Foobar
{
 public string FirstName {get;set;}
 public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Lets say:

```
item.Foos.ElementAt(0).FirstName = "edited name"
```

SaveChanged() is executed but I have the 'old' values on the database and not 'edited name'...

I can see the correct changes in Local in debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your object came from a different context that the one you are using now. In that case you can't do that with a generic because you need to do a foreEach in your Foobar collection and change the state for each item individually.

What you have here is a disconnected entity graph so the entity is disconnected and change tracking is lost. You only set the state of the main entity and so EF assumes that everything else is unchanged.

Jullie Lerman's books is a good source to understand how this works

What I would do is I would keep this method for simple entities but make it virtual so you can inherit this repo to create specific entity repos and override the update method with a more specific implementation suitable to an entity like the one in your example.

An article that helped my to design such a repo was this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the object in a context and saving in another. Remove `using (var ctx = new DataConext())` block, and search for a way to reach the context that loaded the item, then call `SaveChanges();` Another way is pass the context to the method, like this `public int Update(Item item, DbContext context)` and save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Item
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Foobar> Foos {get;set;}
}
```

You need `Include` to include the Foos to the object manager. Right now, it is eager loading. Wherever you are loading the item, you have to include it.

You should use `include`, or you can use `virtual` to have them lazy load.